# save string and associated icon with shared prefs

Tags: string, flutter, icons, sharedpreferences

I'm currently using the shared preferences to save a string list. Every time the page is opened, for every string entry from the list I create a list tile inside a list view. But now I don't want to only save the string, I even want to save an icon with it. But I have absolutely no idea on how to solve this

Here is my current code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:trainings_app/widgets/alertbox_widget.dart';
import 'package:trainings_app/widgets/team_widget.dart';

class TeamScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TeamScreenState createState() => _TeamScreenState();
}

class _TeamScreenState extends State<TeamScreen> {
  late SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  List<String> teams = [];

  IconData? currentIcon;

  @override
  void initState() {
    tryFetchData();
    super.initState();
  }

  void tryFetchData() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (!sharedPreferences.containsKey('teams')) {
      sharedPreferences.setStringList('teams', []);
      return;
    }
    teams = sharedPreferences.getStringList('teams') as List<String>;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: teams.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Team(
            teams[index],
            Icon(currentIcon),
            () => removeTeam(teams[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          newTeam();
        },
        child: Icon(
          CupertinoIcons.add,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void newTeam() {
    showDialog<Alertbox>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Alertbox('Namen auswählen:', addTeam);
      },
    );
  }

  void addTeam(String name, IconData? icon) {
    if (name.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        currentIcon = icon;
        teams.add(name);
      });
    }

    Navigator.pop(context);
    sharedPreferences.setStringList('teams', teams);
  }

  void removeTeam(String name) {
    setState(() {
      teams.remove(name);
    });

    sharedPreferences.setStringList('teams', teams);
  }
}

class Team extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final Icon icon;
  final Function remove;
  const Team(this.name, this.icon, this.remove);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Icon(icon.icon),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
        title: Text(
          name,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          ),
        ),
        trailing: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.delete),
          onPressed: () => remove(),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TeamWidget(name, icon)));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately SharedPreferences in flutter currently doesn't support IconData. So there is no known way to achieve this, but you could use SVG Icons and save the name as string and use the string to show the  particular SVG Icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use each Icon specific id instead of IconData and store it as a List of `Json`:

```
Json.encode({title:"test", icon:61668}
```

and then save it in sharedPref. after that you can recall it as follows:

```
Icon(IconData(**YOUR SELECTED ID**, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'));
```

check the id of each icon here: [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html#constants)

---

The other solution can be using images instead of icons! or using [this site](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select) to convert image to font icon and use it as follows:

```
Icon(IconData(int.parse('0x${e90a}',
    fontFamily: 'family name given in the link above'));
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, this was really informative